# Can I use a singleton paradigm with RCpp?

Tags: c++, r, singleton, rcpp

We are trying to use a singleton paradigm in our R package. When testing the C++ code standalone, we don't experience any problems or errors. When integrated into R with Rcpp, it crashed with no output other than "R has crashed." Our educated guesses point towards a memory issue. We have tried exposing the singleton to Rcpp and hiding it within a different exposed class, and both times it crashed with no output.

We then tried to run an isolated function involving the class that uses the singleton paradigm, and only prints out some information about the class. We ran a function once successfully, but the second run always printed bad values.

Is it possible to use a singleton paradigm with Rcpp?

EDIT: We are using Rcpp modules.

Comment: Just little note: it is pattern, not paradigm :)

Comment: the [page](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) says that classes that you use should be implicitly convertible to SEXP if you're using Rcpp::wrap. But if it uses tmp, then probably there would be compilation error. If this doesn't help, then probably changes from outside (another constructor arguments, function arguments) or inside (protected members) are causing the error.

Comment: We are using modules, not Rcpp::wrap. I'll try to add some code later, but it's a complex packages with many c++ classes interacting, so it's difficult to isolate a single section of code.

Comment: Post your code to GitHub and write the link!

Comment: Sure. We do that a lot.

Comment: https://github.com/jeremyrogers/RibModelFramework/tree/testing.


src/include/CodonTable.h has the singleton structure.


There's another repo in https://github.com/jeremyrogers/RibModelDev that contains Rscripts that we use to run. The script in question is called runROCmodel.R

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible, unless you are somehow able to implement a Singleton class that has a (public) default constructor. I'll use the following example to demonstrate - where the second class was just a sanity check to make sure the issue wasn't specific to static objects:

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 

class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton& get() {
        static Singleton s;
        return s;
    }

    void method() const {
        Rcpp::Rcout << "...\n";
    }

private:
    Singleton() {};
    Singleton(const Singleton&);
    void operator=(const Singleton&);
};

class NonStatic {
public:
    void method() {
        Rcpp::Rcout << "...\n";
    }

private:
    NonStatic() {}
    NonStatic(const NonStatic&);
    void operator=(const NonStatic&);

};

using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_MODULE(Singleton) {

    class_<Singleton>("Singleton")
    .method("method", &Singleton::method)
    ;

    class_<NonStatic>("NonStatic")
    .method("method", &NonStatic::method)
    ;
}
```

---

Compiling this with `sourceCpp` and attempting to call `$method()` crashed my session for either class. If you are on a *nix machine you can investigate this by starting R from a terminal with `R --debugger=gdb` (or your debugger of choice).

```
nathan@nathan-laptop:~/tmp$ R --debugger=gdb 
## [omitted] 
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) R
## [omitted] 
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("singleton.cpp")
[Thread 0x7ffff13fd700 (LWP 18644) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff3bfe700 (LWP 18643) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff43ff700 (LWP 18642) exited]
R> ls()
[1] "NonStatic" "Singleton"
R> x <- new(Singleton)
R> x$method()
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Rcpp::not_initialized'
  what():  C++ object not initialized (missing default constructor?)

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
```

and likewise for the other class:

```
R> Rcpp::sourceCpp("singleton.cpp")
[Thread 0x7ffff13fd700 (LWP 18737) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff3bfe700 (LWP 18736) exited]
[Thread 0x7ffff43ff700 (LWP 18735) exited]
R> x <- new(NonStatic)
R> x$method()
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Rcpp::not_initialized'
  what():  C++ object not initialized (missing default constructor?)

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
```